# Is there a synonym for checked

Tags: synonyms

Is there a synonym for checked?

I am writing about the implementation process of my app and I would like to know whether there is a synonym for the word **checked** that I can use in other sentences.

> Next, the value of the flag variable is **checked** to know when the system has to delete the related data from the database.

Comment: You can use *verify.*

Comment: Better yet, avoid using flag variables altogether. Your code and your documentation will both be simplified.

Comment: You could check [here](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/check).

Answer (score 3):

The word **tested** comes to mind:

> ...the value of the flag variable is **tested**...

as you will be **testing** the value of the variable when you **check** it.

For documentation purposes, it may be more comprehensive if the sentence was worded as follows:

> If the **flag variable** is **true**, then the system will **delete** the related data from the database.

The details of **variable**, **state**, and **action** are all clearly stated.

Comment: +1 for clarity by avoiding "check" or "test" and skipping to the *relevant value* of the test.

Answer (score 0):

### Verify / Verification

This seems like it would be the most direct synonym to the more vulgar/colloquial "check". In your case, this would be specifically definition 2 of the following from [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/verify):

> **Verify**
>   verb (used with object), verified, verifying.
>   1. to prove the truth of, as by evidence or testimony; confirm; substantiate: Events verified his prediction.
>   2. to ascertain the truth or correctness of, as by examination, research, or comparison: to verify a spelling.
>   3. to act as ultimate proof or evidence of; serve to confirm.
>   4. Law. to prove or confirm (an allegation). to state to be true, especially in legal use, formally or upon oath.

Used in context:

> Next, the value of the variable is *verified* [...]

This verb is frequently used in programming, security and technology in general.

Comment: "Assertion" is _way_ too strong to be considered a synonym for this example.